# TextAlign underfined with dynamic as parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: ![enter image description here]

Undefined name 'TextAlign'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

```
 Text(
                'This ia a study app you can use it as you want',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: AppColors.onSurfaceTextColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
```

Flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.856], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\Flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (6 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code (version 1.70.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.46.0

[√] Connected device (5 available)
    • ASUS Z01QD (mobile) • 127.0.0.1:5555 • android-x64    • Android 9 (API 28)
    • ASUS Z01QD (mobile) • emulator-5554  • android-x64    • Android 9 (API 28)
    • Windows (desktop)   • windows        • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.856]
    • Chrome (web)        • chrome         • web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.102
    • Edge (web)          • edge           • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 104.0.1293.63

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Can you include full snippet, there is no issue with current snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I changed the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed with the newest version of flutter(3.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

- If fails do `flutter upgrade` or `flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: still did not work. what I did not understand is the parameter type, why it shows dynamic when it suppose to be TextAlign.

Comment: does it happen for all project

Comment: Yes. It still happens even when I opened the project with Android Studio.

Comment: Try `flutter upgrade --force` or reinstall the flutter

Answer (score 0):

Close and Open the project if not then IDE.